# Dynamically created component is not loading in body of div after summer 16 release

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I am adding Lightning component dynamically to the body of a Div. It was working fine before Summer 16 release. I am not getting any error for same but component is not adding to div'body.

Component Code:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
 <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
   <div id="QuestionsDiv" aura:id="QuestionsDiv" width="70%">                
 </div>
```

Controller Code:

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
      helper.doInit(component, event, helper);   
}
})
```

Helper Code:

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var self = this;
    var divCmp = component.find("QuestionsDiv");
$A.createComponent("c:TextBoxComponent",
                {
                    "Id" : 'textid',
                    "inputText" : 'Enter Text',
                    "inputValue":'testvalue'
                }, 
                 function(newCmp){
                     var divBody = divCmp.get("v.body");
                     divBody.push(newCmp);
                     divCmp.set("v.body", divBody); 
                });   

 $A.createComponent("c:InputNumberComponent",
                {
                    "Id" : 'InputNumberid',
                    "inputText" : "Enter Number",
                    "inputValue":"testvalue"                        
                }, 
                 function(newCmp){                       
                   self.insertNewCmp(divCmp,newCmp);
                });
},
insertNewCmp:function(divCmp,newCmp){
    var divBody = divCmp.get("v.body");
    divBody.push(newCmp);
    divCmp.set("v.body", divBody);        
}
})
```

"c:TextBoxComponent" Component Markup:

```
<aura:component >  
<aura:attribute type="String" name="Id" />
<aura:attribute type="String" name="inputText" />
<aura:attribute type="String" name="inputValue" />       
<div class="slds-form-element">             
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="{!Id}">{!v.inputText}/label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
      <ui:inputText aura:id="{!v.Id}" class="slds-input"  value="{!v.inputValue}"/>            
   </div>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

"InputNumberComponent" Component Markup:

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute type="String" name="Id" />
<aura:attribute type="String" name="inputText" />
 <aura:attribute type="String" name="inputValue" />
<aura:attribute type="double" name="waitage"/>

<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label">{!v.inputText}</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
     <ui:inputNumber aura:id="{!v.Id}" class="slds-input"  value="{!v.inputValue}" placeholder="{!v.inputText}"/>
   </div>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: can you post your component's markup code which creates `c:TextBoxComponent`?

Comment: do you have `{!v.body}` line in your parent component?If so please post your Parent component's markup,controller,helper.js too.So that i can look in further.

Comment: Praveen - I am not using {!v.body} tag but using a div i.e <div id="QuestionsDiv" aura:id="QuestionsDiv" width="70%">, In which I am trying to add component

Comment: could just post more code ?.so that i can debug further

Comment: also are you really sure,the `insertNewCmp` method is being called? try putting `console.log` to check

Comment: Shilpa - i have updated the answer.Let me know whether it solves your issue or not.

Comment: Praveen - insertNewCmp method is calling, I checked by putting logs. Even component is being pushed to the body object but not rendering on HTML. I was working fine before summer 16 release.

Comment: did u try the code given in the answer?. I tried the same in a Summer 16 org and it works for me.

Comment: If it does not solve your issue,then you have to post enough code (as i already asked in my previous comment)to debug the issue.

Comment: Yes, using same code. Please find component log for divBody, after pushing new component - divBody: SecureComponent: markup://c:TextBoxComponent {1:137;a}{ key: {"Zc":"c"} }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41157/discussion-between-praveen-and-shilpa).

Comment: After some investigation, I observed that Only one component is loading to DOM element. Components I tried to add in body are being added in body object but only a single component is rendered in DOM.

Comment: Shilpa - I think my answer should solve your issue but if not you should post more code,only then i can help you out.

Comment: Praveen - I have posted my complete code. Please check.

Comment: Shilpa - I updated the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$A.createComponent`,why not use `$A.createComponents` which better serves the purpose, to create multiple components dynamically(in your case `c:TextBoxComponent` and `c:InputNumberComponent`) in a single call.

Once you get back newly created Components(which is an array) in the callback,just concat with the div's component.

you can refer the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm) for more info on dynamically creating components.

your helper should look like this:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var self = this;
        var divCmp = component.find("QuestionsDiv");
        $A.createComponents(
            [
                ["c:TextBoxComponent",
                    {
                        "Id" : 'testid',
                        "inputText" : 'testlabel',
                        "inputValue":'testvalue'
                    }
                ],
                ["c:InputNumberComponent",
                    {
                        "Id" : 'InputNumberid',
                        "inputText" : "Enter Number",
                        "inputValue":"testvalue"                        
                    }
                ]
            ], 
            function(newlyCreatedCmps, status){                         
               if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    self.insertNewCmps(divCmp,newlyCreatedCmps);   
               }
               else{
                    console.log('error');
               }
            }
        );
    },
    insertNewCmps:function(divCmp,newCmps){
        var divBody = divCmp.get("v.body");
        divCmp.set("v.body", divBody.concat(newCmps));       
    }
});
```

Comment: Praveen - I am not adding component to body but in a div's body by using below code: divCmp.set("v.body", divBody);

Comment: ok got it.will update the answer

Comment: Praveen - I can not use $A.createComponents in my code, because I am adding component conditionally. But using "concat", in place of "Push" to add component in body, resolved my issue. Thank Praveen for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue we just released the fix for in the .9 patch for Summer'16 (not all instances have it yet) specific to running components under LockerService and dynamic updates to v.body where updates to the body are not rendering. What instance is your org on?